# My simple C program crashes

Tags: c, variables, crash

I am trying to have a variable whose value is a word like "facebook". However, I cannot have it easily in C. Instead of using tiring ways(I did it but it was too long, there is no need for this.) I thought I can replace "facebook" with a float which is like 123456789 etc. My code is like that:

```
printf("Enter the number.\n");

scanf("%f", website);

if(website==32463774)
{
    printf("You wrote facebook.");
}
```

When the program comes to this scanf line after printing "Enter the number.", it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `scanf("%f", website);` --> `scanf("%f", &website);`. BTW use `double` or `long int` instead of `float`.

Comment: 32463774 is not a `float`

Comment: 1) enable compiler warnings, 2) read the function manuals, 3) look for existing example uses of the function.

Comment: 4) Learn to use GDB.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code out, but I think you shared just a pattern of it.

```
scanf("%f", &website);
```

Maybe it was the reason of your crashed program.
But easily you can store strings in char type of variables.

I tried to store the value variable, as string in the website variable.

My code looks like this:

```
//The stored string
char website[15];
printf("Enter the website:\n");
scanf("%s", website);

printf("The stored website: %s\n", website);
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` takes the address of the variable you want to write, not the variable itself.

Here's what you want:

```
scanf("%f", &website);
```

Under the hood, addresses and integers are pretty much the same. They vary based on implementation, but at the end of the day, they are both numbers of some length. The length might be different, but they are just numbers. That's why the compiler isn't yelling at you for this; it does know that you probably don't want to do this, but it is trusting that you know what you're doing and letting you do it anyway.

An address is the location of something in memory. C functions can take the address of something, go there, modify it, and then return, allowing the calling function to go back to that address (which the calling function already knew) and get whatever the callee put there. Most newer languages would let you pass in data, and then get it back by having it returned, but C doesn't like to do that very much, so it has addresses.

Imagine you have a broken record player (your variable that you want changed). A newer language would say that you go see the repairman (function), give him the record player (pass it in as a parameter), and then he gives you (returns) the fixed record player, and you leave. C can't pick up whole record players though. All C can carry are Post-It notes with street addresses on them. So what C does is goes to the repairman with the address where the record player is on a sticky note. The repairman goes to the house, fixes the record player, and then comes back to the guy who called him and says how it went. To get the record player, the caller goes back to the house and uses it there, now fixed.

The address is an address, and the record player is the value of a variable. `scanf()` wants an address, so it can put the number in a house and you can get it later. You gave it the variable though. You gave it the record player. The repairman (function) is expecting a sticky note, so he just tries to find an address written on the record player somewhere. He finds the serial number, and goes around town looking for that address. Of course, there is no such address; he just goes around looking forever and dies of thirst. The program crashes.

Long story short, give `scanf()` an address.

Also, I don't think you need to use a `float` here. An `int` should be enough.